Unable to Load related Entities/Documents Successfully in Marten
This seems like a simple problem but I have been having a challenge loading a document via the entity with related document with Marten documentDB on postgres for the past 2 days. I'm also using the latest release of the library (7.26.0). Please patiently go through my work so far:
KycVerificationStep (Entity)
public class KycVerificationStep : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Icon { get; private set; }
    public int Order { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DateUpdated { get; private set; }

    private KycVerificationStep() { }

    private KycVerificationStep(
        string name,
        string description,
        string icon,
        int order,
        IKycVerificationStepDomainService domainService)
    {
        CheckRule(new KycStepMustBeUniqueRule(domainService, name));
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Icon = icon;
        Order = order;
        DateCreated = SystemClock.Now;
        Code = $"Step {Order}";

        AddDomainEvent(new KycVerificationStepCreatedDomainEvent(Id));
    }

    public static KycVerificationStep Create(
        string name,
        string description,
        string icon,
        int order,
        IKycVerificationStepDomainService domainService)
    {
        return new KycVerificationStep(name, description, icon, order, domainService);
    }

    // shortened for brevity   
}

MemberKycVerificationStep
public class MemberKycVerificationStep : BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public Guid KycVerificationStepId { get; private set; }

    public KycVerificationStep KycVerificationStep { get; private set; }

    public Guid MemberId { get; private set; }

    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeOffset DateUpdated { get; private set; }

    private MemberKycVerificationStep() { }

    private MemberKycVerificationStep(
        Guid kycVerificationStepId,
        Guid memberId)
    {
        Id = $"{memberId}_{kycVerificationStepId}";
        KycVerificationStepId = kycVerificationStepId;
        MemberId = memberId;
        Status = VerificationStatus.NotStarted.ToString();

        AddDomainEvent(new MemberKycVerificationStepCreatedDomainEvent(MemberId, KycVerificationStepId));
    }

    public static MemberKycVerificationStep Create(
        Guid kycVerificationStepId,
        Guid memberId)
    {
        return new MemberKycVerificationStep(kycVerificationStepId, memberId);
    }
}

Here's how I try to query MemberKycVerificationStep the get the KycVerificationStep By MemberId.
public async Task<Result<IPagedList<MemberKycVerificationStepDto>>> Handle(GetAllVerificationStepsByUserQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    KycVerificationStep included = null;
    var results = await _querySession
        .Query<MemberKycVerificationStep>()
        .Include<KycVerificationStep>(x => included = x)
            .On(x => x.KycVerificationStepId)
        .Where(x => x.MemberId == request.UserId)
        .Select(x => new MemberKycVerificationStepDto
        {
            KycVerificationStepId = x.KycVerificationStepId,
            Name = included != null ? included.Name : "",
            DateUpdated = x.DateUpdated,
            Status = "x.Status",
            MemberId = x.MemberId
        })
        .ToPagedListAsync(request.PageIndex, request.PageSize, cancellationToken);
    return await Result<IPagedList<MemberKycVerificationStepDto>>.SuccessAsync(results);
}

But I get the following exception which comes from the linq expressions implementation from Marten.

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue
value)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression
node)    at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.Visit(Expression node)
at
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
node)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.Visit(Expression node)    at
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression
node)    at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.Visit(Expression node)
at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.ReadBinding(MemberAssignment
binding)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression
node)    at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser.Visit(Expression node)
at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectParser..ctor(ISerializer serializer,
IQueryableMemberCollection members, Expression expression)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectorVisitor.ToSelectTransform(Expression
selectExpression, ISerializer serializer)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectorVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression
node)    at Marten.Linq.Parsing.SelectorVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Marten.Linq.CollectionUsage.BuildTopStatement(IMartenSession
session, IQueryableMemberCollection collection, IDocumentStorage
storage, QueryStatistics statistics)    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.LinqQueryParser.BuildStatements()    at
Marten.Linq.Parsing.LinqQueryParser.BuildListHandlerT    at
Marten.Linq.MartenLinqQueryable1.ToListAsync[TResult](CancellationToken token)    at Marten.Pagination.PagedList1.InitAsync(IQueryable1 queryable, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize, CancellationToken token)  at Marten.Pagination.PagedList1.CreateAsync(IQueryable1 queryable, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize, CancellationToken token)    at Marten.Pagination.PagedListQueryableExtensions.ToPagedListAsync[T](IQueryable1
queryable, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize, CancellationToken token)

The data for the MemberKycVerificationStep document is present in the db. But I don't understand why I'm getting a null reference. Please help.

Prepare issue for Marten, looks like it is their bug. Anyway, looking at callstack and I have idea: replace included != null ? included.Name : "" with just included.Name ?? ""

What does the stored document record for that MemberKycVerificationStep look like? Does it contain the expected KycVerificationStep data with a populated Id?

@StevePy Thanks for your response. Here's a document record for your reference
{""Id"": ""8ed8b584-4516-4b9b-b2b7-4ec24ec5acd5_01910787-33fb-48c7-af7b-a24e0e8e530b"", ""Status"": ""Not started"", ""MemberId"": ""8ed8b584-4516-4b9b-b2b7-4ec24ec5acd5"", ""DateUpdated"": ""0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"", ""DomainEvents"": [], ""KycVerificationStepId"": ""01910787-33fb-48c7-af7b-a24e0e8e530b""}

@SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for your response. I created the issue about the same time I created this question here.
I got a null reference exception (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.') on the Name property of KycVerificationStep entity

Svyatoslav's example should have been included?.Name ?? "" or better, included?.Name ?? string.Empty though there can sometimes be issues passing/parsing    ternary operations, your #null check should work, that doesn't explain the key issue. One small thing I see, is it a typo in your example but your "x.Status" is in quotes which would be interpreted as a string. I'd consider pulling the query apart to just get the member without the include and no select, then get the member with the include and no select projection and inspect what comes back.

@StevePy It's was actually a test to find out if "x.Status" will be returned as Status of MemberKycVerificationStepDto but instead it returns it's value from the db "Not Started". Frankly, the library behaves strangely sometimes. I have other entities (without dependent object) that the querying works well. But this is just strange.
